# GA4 limits and sampling

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

In the internet i tryed to find information, but it very hard ,because in any forums i found diffrent information.
How many hits i can collct in **GA4** property in one month without sampling and limits?
In **GA3** i could collect only **10M** in one month, but in **GA4** i don't know.
And after **10M** in month, data will be collecting or Google will stop collect new data more than 10M hits?

In official **Google** docs - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11202874?hl=en
They say Explore sampling limits = 10M events per query
What does it mean?
It is impossible that in the report there were more than **10M** lines?

Answer (score 1):

It means that when you generate a non-standard report involving 10 million hits, sampling is applied. In that case you can reduce the time frame to involve fewer hits.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to analyze data without sampling is to export your data from GA4 into BigQuery. This is a very good feature that's now available in the free plan.

The main limitation of this, though, is that you can only export up to 1M events per day. In order to avoid this limit, you can use something like [Parallel Tracking](https://reflectivedata.com/how-to-avoid-google-analytics-4-ga4-bigquery-export-quota-limit-of-1-million-hits/).